# How to retrieve and set mapping of project on TFS

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mapping, workspace

How can I get mapping of current project on TFS 2010? I need to take single file, find out its mapping and with that information I want to find this file on another computer, which has mapped same workspace. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: This is a broad question. Can you tell us what you've done to tackle the problem so far?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can find the mapping info at File menu -> Source Control -> Workspaces.

Comment: I've got an application, which works with resx files which are under source control of TFS. I need to store relative paths of chosen resx files, which are located on my pc, that if somebody opens this app on other machine, it must be able find these files by setting of his workspace. So I think I need to find out relative paths of these files by my workspace setting and then I need to find local files based on setting of some user workspace. So I ask how can I achieve this. I'm new to TFS, so I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found solution by myself. 
First I get server name for every file

```
try
{
WorkspaceInfo wsi = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(localFileName);
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(wsi.ServerUri);
Workspace wr = wsi.GetWorkspace(tfs);
string ret = wr.TryGetServerItemForLocalItem(localFileName);
return ret;
}
catch
{
  return null;
}
```

and than, on another computer, I can load local names

```
try
{
Uri serverUri = new Uri(uri);
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(serverUri);
VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));   
Workstation.Current.EnsureUpdateWorkspaceInfoCache(vcs, Environment.UserName);
Workspace wr = vcs.GetWorkspace(Environment.MachineName, Environment.UserName);
string ret=wr.TryGetLocalItemForServerItem(serverFileName);
return ret;
}
catch
{
  return null;
}
```

It has some limitations, but works perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit unclear.

Whats your main goal?

If you install [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm#tfssidekicks2010) you can have a view called "Workspace Sidekick".

There you can filter by computername, Owner (User) and access date (first/last).

With TFS Sidekicks its a little bit easier to find mapped workspaces.

[image: Workspace Sidekick]

Comment: Defo recommend TFS Sidekicks, however I'm not sure the approach to the problem is correct, really the file should be located relatively in a reasonable way, if someone has used some dodgy local mappings then they should follow a standard setup.